# Error when interpolating $e^{2x} - x$ by a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation

I was reading [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151001/lagrange-interpolating-polynomials-error-bound), and I found the top answer (by the user Amzoti) very strange.

The question asks to interpolate $f(x) = e^{2x} - x$ at $x_0 = 1$, $x_1 = 1.25$, and $x_2 = 1.6$, then approximate $f(1.4)$ using the polynomial, and finally calculate the error.
The strange part is the error.

The well-known formula for the error is
$$E(x) = \frac {1}{3!} f^{(3)}(\xi(x)) (x - 1)(x - 1.25)(x - 1.6).$$

What I think is:
$$\begin{align*}|E(1.4)| &\le \frac 16 \left( \max_{y \in [1, 1.6]}|f^{(3)}(y)| \right)|(1.4 - 1)(1.4 - 1.25)(1.4 - 1.6)|\\
\\
& = \left( \max_{y \in [1, 1.6]}|f^{(3)}(y)| \right) (0.002).
\end{align*}
$$
However, Amzoti did

$$|E(1.4)| \le \frac 16 \max_{y \in [1, 1.6]} |f^{(3)}(y)| \cdot \max_{y \in [1, 1.6]} |(y - 1)(y - 1.25)(y - 1.6)|$$
This is

A) A worse error bound

B) More work

Isn't my approach correct? Am I missing something? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your approach is correct. E.g. it correctly gives a zero error when evaluated at the nodes, while the approach in the quoted answer doesn't.

Comment: @HansEngler Thank you for your comment. The quoted answer also uses the formula $E(x) = \frac {1}{3!} f^{(3)}(\xi(x)) (x - 1)(x - 1.25)(x - 1.6)$ for the error, which is zero at the nodes. However, Amozi seems to bound $E(1.4)$ in a way that is both worse than my bound, $\textbf{and}$ takes more work. I was wondering if I'm making a mistake with my bounding.

Comment: The error bound coming from your approach should be $|E(x)| \le \frac{M}{3} |x-1||x-1.25||x-1.6|$, where $M$ is a bound for $|f^{(3)}(x)|$ on the interval of interest. That's what you used for $x = 1.4$.